# Finding the length of longest repeating?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried plenty of different methods to achieve this, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
reps=[]
len_charac=0
def longest_charac(strng)
    for i in range(len(strng)):
        if strng[i] == strng[i+1]:
            if strng[i] in reps:
                reps.append(strng[i])
                len_charac=len(reps)
    return len_charac
```

Comment: What errors do you get when you run the code ?

Comment: Are you looking for the longest repeated string or character? Would the answer to "abcabcabcff" be "abcabcabc" or "ff"? Also, are you looking for the longest in terms of number of repeats or longest in terms of the string resulting from the repeats (is the answer to" abcabcffff" "abcabc", "ffff", 2 or 4? Are non-sequential repeats counted ("abcffabcfabc")?

Comment: what is `len_substring` your function returning to? the global variable you declared just before your function?

Comment: Sorry, I meant longest repeating character, not substring. And yes, it should be returning to the global variable

Comment: there are a lot of methodical problems in your code, we'll clear soon. but first of all, you also have a logic error in your code - in first if statement, 
`strng[i+1]` will cause error, because inside this scope (`for i in range(len(strng))`) when i takes the maximum value, i+1 will cause index error. change it to `len(string)-1`. then try a bit.

Comment: @pythonbeginner4556 It's better to provide the code which can run correctly. For your code, there is no `:` after `def longest_charac(strng)` when compile, and  at least `IndexError: string index out of range` when run.

Answer (score 7):

Simple solution:

```
def longest_substring(strng):
    len_substring=0
    longest=0
    for i in range(len(strng)):
        if i > 0:
            if strng[i] != strng[i-1]:
                len_substring = 0
        len_substring += 1
        if len_substring > longest:
            longest = len_substring          
    return longest
```

Iterates through the characters in the string and checks against the previous one. If they are different then the count of repeating characters is reset to zero, then the count is incremented. If the current count beats the current record (stored in `longest`) then it becomes the new longest.

Comment: Not to disparage but it looks like sub-string length variable gets incremented no matter what. You set the length to zero, so it works, but the way you worded it it sounded like you meant it doesn't get incremented if they are different.

Comment: @RonThompson Yes you're right I've clarified the wording

Comment: I find this one line alternative clearer `longest = max(longest, len_substring)`

Answer (score 7):

Remember in Python counting loops and indexing strings aren't usually needed.  There is also a builtin `max` function:

```
def longest(s):
    maximum = count = 0
    current = ''
    for c in s:
        if c == current:
            count += 1
        else:
            count = 1
            current = c
        maximum = max(count,maximum)
    return maximum
```

Output:

```
>>> longest('')
0
>>> longest('aab')
2
>>> longest('a')
1
>>> longest('abb')
2
>>> longest('aabccdddeffh')
3
>>> longest('aaabcaaddddefgh')
4
```

Comment: Upvoting for the cleanest of iterative solutions... pretty much equivalent in approach to my suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Compare two things and there is one relation between them:

```
'a' == 'a'
  True
```

Compare three things, and there are two relations:

```
'a' == 'a' == 'b'
  True    False
```

Combine these ideas - repeatedly compare things with the things next to them, and the chain gets shorter each time:

```
'a' == 'a' == 'b'
  True == False
     False
```

It takes one reduction for the 'b' comparison to be False, because there was one 'b'; two reductions for the 'a' comparison to be False because there were two 'a'. Keep repeating until the relations are all all False, and that is how many consecutive equal characters there were.

```
def f(s):
    repetitions = 0
    while any(s):
        repetitions += 1
        s = [ s[i] and s[i] == s[i+1] for i in range(len(s)-1) ]

    return repetitions

>>> f('aaabcaaddddefgh')
4
```

NB. matching characters at the start become True, only care about comparing the Trues with anything, and stop when all the Trues are gone and the list is all Falses.

It can also be squished into a recursive version, passing the depth in as an optional parameter:

```
def f(s, depth=1):
    s = [ s[i] and s[i]==s[i+1] for i in range(len(s)-1) ]

    return f(s, depth+1) if any(s) else depth


>>> f('aaabcaaddddefgh')
4
```

I stumbled on this while trying for something else, but it's quite pleasing.

Comment: Pleasing, and elegantly explained.

Answer (score 3):

You can use itertools.groupby to solve this pretty quickly, it will group characters together, and then you can sort the resulting list by length and get the last entry in the list as follows:

```
 from itertools import groupby
 print(sorted([list(g) for k, g in groupby('aaabcaaddddefgh')],key=len)[-1])
```

This should give you:

```
 ['d', 'd', 'd', 'd']
```

Comment: From the question: *"I am trying to keep this simple, and achieve this without importing any functions or modules."*

Comment: there is nothing wrong with multiple answers that illustrate different parts of the language, In the future someone who doesn't have the same constraints on not importing anything might want a solution to this problem and will benefit by learning about the itertools solution.

Comment: "Keep this simple" and "without importing any functions" are contradicting requirements. Please use the language to its fullest!

Comment: Good in principle - I'd personally get rid of the `sorted` part though and use `max` instead - you can get away without creating a list then

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
def longestRun(s):
    if len(s) == 0: return 0
    runs = ''.join('*' if x == y else ' ' for x,y in zip(s,s[1:]))
    starStrings = runs.split()
    if len(starStrings) == 0: return 1
    return 1 + max(len(stars) for stars in starStrings)
```

Output:

```
>>> longestRun("aaabcaaddddefgh")
4
```

Comment: This is the fastest solution.

Answer (score 2):

First off, Python is not my primary language, but I can still try to help.

1) you look like you are exceeding the bounds of the array. On the last iteration, you check the last character against the character *beyond* the last character. This normally leads to undefined behavior.

2) you start off with an empty reps[] array and compare every character to see if it's in it. Clearly, that check will fail every time and your append is within that if statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
def longest_charac(string):
    longest = 0
    if string:
        flag = string[0]
        tmp_len = 0
        for item in string:
            if item == flag:
                tmp_len += 1
            else:
                flag = item
                tmp_len = 1
            if tmp_len > longest:
                longest = tmp_len
    return longest
```

This is my solution. Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just for context, here is a recursive approach that avoids dealing with loops:

```
def max_rep(prev, text, reps, rep=1):                                              
    """Recursively consume all characters in text and find longest repetition.  
    Args                                                                           
        prev: string of previous character                                         
        text: string of remaining text                                             
        reps: list of ints of all reptitions observed                              
        rep: int of current repetition observed                                    
    """                                                                            
    if text == '': return max(reps)                                                  
    if prev == text[0]:                                                            
        rep += 1                                                                   
    else:                                                                          
        rep = 1                                                                    
    return max_rep(text[0], text[1:], reps + [rep], rep)
```

Tests:

```
>>> max_rep('', 'aaabcaaddddefgh', [])
4
>>> max_rep('', 'aaaaaabcaadddddefggghhhhhhh', [])
7
```